# How to handle multiple go-routines closing the same channel?

Tags: go, goroutine

I am having 2 go-routines reading from a single channel. After 4 seconds, I cancel the context and terminate the select loop. Before terminating the loop I call close on the channel, since there are 2 go-routines the close gets called twice and causes a panic because one of the go-routines would have already closed the channel. Currently I am using a recover to recover from the panic, is there a better way of doing this?

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func numberGen(ctx context.Context, numChan chan int) {
    num := 0
    doneCh := ctx.Done()
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Println("recovered from ", r)
        }
    }()
    for {
        select {
        case <-doneCh:
            fmt.Println("done generating...")
            close(numChan)
            return
        default:
            num++
            numChan <- num
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    ctx, cancelFn := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    numChan := make(chan int)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)
    go numberGen(ctx, numChan)
    go numberGen(ctx, numChan)

    go func(cfn context.CancelFunc) {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
        cfn()
    }(cancelFn)

    for n := range numChan {
        fmt.Println("received value ", n)
    }

    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
}
```

Comment: Avoid this situation in the first place. One go routine should be responsible for closing the channel. For example, your generators can exit when the context is cancelled and your main routine, or another routine, can close the channel when their WaitGroup is done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Close the channel after the goroutines are done sending values.

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(2)
go numberGen(ctx, numChan, &wg)
go numberGen(ctx, numChan, &wg)

go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(numChan)
}()
```

Update `numberGen` to call `Done()` on the wait group.  Also, remove the call to `close`.

```
func numberGen(ctx context.Context, numChan chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    ...
```